# Reduced F# performance on x64 target?

Tags: performance, f#, 64-bit

Recently, I was surprised by the behavior of the F# compiler when using x64 target compared to x86. The same application works with the following time on different targets:

```
x86:            68ms
Any CPU/x64:    160ms
```

For me this results are strange.
The results differ by almost two-fold. I assumed that on 64-bit processor, 64-bit operating system the 64-bit application will work faster than 32-bit one.

So question is: What is wrong? Problem is in compiler or it's my fault somewhere?

Environment: Core 2 Duo and Windows 7 x64.
F# application: FsYacc/FsLex language parser. .Net 4 Framework.

Comment: Your measurements are definitely suspect.  Code generation for x64 and AnyCPU is identical.

Comment: Rechecked it again - you're right. But x86 still faster than x64.

Comment: Are you saying the compiler is slower or the code generated is slower?

Comment: It is difficult to tell without the actual source code. My guess: the x86 CLR still has a more optimize jitter. If you have many functions, as it may happen in F#, missing inlining can be the culprit. Also, iirc, tailcall can make the difference and they be missing in the x64 jitter. Also, remember that in x64 pointers, including function pointers, are always double the size. So it is not true that a 64 bit app will always be faster (if it has to move double the data around.. plus cache pressure due to bigger data)

Comment: Reference on missing tail call optimization here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jomo_fisher/archive/2007/09/19/adventures-in-f-tail-recursion-in-three-languages.aspx (may be no more valid, as it was written on 2007, but...)

Comment: I would suggest using a profiler to find what specific bits of code run slower in 64 bit mode

Comment: Are you sure that the rest of the build settings are identical? I had a similar problem some time ago, and I discovered to my embarrassment that I built the x86 version in release mode, but the x64 in debug mode (optimizations disabled etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can happen for programs that use a lot of pointer-heavy data structures, since a pointer is 8 bytes on 64-bit, whereas it's 4 bytes on 32-bit.  The bottleneck in pointer chasing code is cache misses.  In the limit where 100% of your code is chasing pointers, you'll incur twice as many cache misses on 64-bit as on 32-bit, hence the 2x slowdown.

For other types of programs, though, 64-bit can be faster than 32-bit, at least on x86/x64.  x64 has twice as many general purpose registers as 32-bit x86, newer instructions like SSE/SSE2 are guaranteed to be available on x64 but not on 32-bit x86, and with more address space you can make different space-speed tradeoffs, such as storing instead of recomputing values or memory mapping large files.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Int64 instead of Int32 in your app?  Have you tried changing out to an 8-bit character set?  How do these things affect perf?

Do you run a regular hard drive or SSD?

Comment: I have no int's or other n-bit specific types in my app - it's simple language parser, using FsLex and FsYacc with FSharp PowerPack.
BTW SSD.

Comment: @GregC FsLex and FsYacc rely heavily on uint16, does this help?

Comment: Sounds like there are places in FsLex and FsYacc that could be rewritten using Intel intrinsics (SSE), combined with C++/CLI.  If it's a purely F# library, I wouldn't be surprised that it runs slower on x64, possibly due to rate of memory access limitations.  In my prior experience, I was able to push 20% faster than tight C loop when reordering bytes.

Comment: I asked about SSD because HDD latency could skew your small numbers.